# What is the title to this question?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

What is the first clue to this question?

What is the second clue to this question?

Hint

> What is the hint to this question?

Comment: mmmmm.... What?

Comment: Do you wish to submit that as an answer? There is a possibility that someone can justify an answer different from the intended one. If so then upvotes will decide who wins.

Comment: Can't say I'm a fan of this type of 'puzzle'.

Comment: @Tryth: Probably because it's not a puzzle.

Comment: @Deusovi - What is it then?

Comment: Either a set of questions too easy to be a puzzle, or something where the "correct answer" is pulled out of nowhere, depending on which one of the two current answers is 'right' (IF one of them is right, that is)

Comment: Mostly, my motivation is to come up with new genres of puzzle.  I do this on an experimental basis. I have had some very successful puzzles and some very unsuccessful ones. This is one based on philosophy (there is no philosophy tag). It is related to the Liar Paradox (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liar_paradox) in that it uses self-referential sentences. Depending on the response from the community I may develop other such questions or decide not to.

Comment: @Chasly-from-UK: I have thoroughly enjoyed your puzzles so far, and I find them innovating and refreshing. The community is broad, and there is not need to adapt your puzzles to please a particular segment of the community.

Comment: I applaud your wanting to create new types of puzzles;  however, a lot of your puzzles seem to be poorly defined. I suggest making your puzzles a bit more clear before posting. However, this is just my opinion; other people may disagree, especially because my preference for "enigmatic puzzles" is puzzles in [this style](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6453/a-well-balanced-puzzle-logic-puzzles-in-visual-disguise).

Comment: @Deusovi - You have a point. However, as I understand it, the original motivation for this site was not simply to post puzzles and get answers but to tackle the problems of puzzle-making.  By submitting a puzzle such as this I think I can achieve both. I get feedback on how easy or difficult my puzzles are by seeing how quickly they are solved and I also receive useful criticism--as I just have from you. Incidentally, what suggestions do you have for making this one clearer?-- I'd be interested. Thanks.

Comment: @Chasly: Well, that depends on the intended answer. I'm personally not sure what you're going for. I assumed it ws the answer that The Dark Truth posted (which doesn't really make it a puzzle IMO), but it's still possible that it could be something completely different that would make me completely change my opinion/ideas.

Comment: Hi @chaslyfromUK. I was wondering whether you might be able to post further clues to this question, or even your intended answer? I'm very interested in what the intended answer was!

Comment: Ping! @chaslyfromUK is back on SE, and I'm still dying to know the intended answer to this question. Seriously, I saw you'd posted on worldbuilding and I remembered this question. From three years ago. That's how important it is to me. Which is slightly disturbing... but hey.

Answer (score 9):

Well clearly:

> "**What**" is the answer to this question!

because:

> "What" is the title, the first clue, the second, and indeed the hint.

Answer (score 7):

Just a guess:

> What is the answer to this question?

Comment: Seems to be the best guess.

Comment: Personally, I think your formatting is a bit off the mark...

Comment: Good idea, but than "What is the question to this question?" must be first line in the OP's formulation.

Answer (score 4):

They're "What is the title to this question?", "What is the first clue to this question?", "What is the second clue to this question?", and "What is the hint to this question?", respectively.

Comment: Does this count as "parallel thinking"? It's clearly not lateral thinking...

Comment: @Andy: I just answered the questions that were asked. My answer is indisputably a correct answer. :P

Comment: lol, I can't disagree - I just wondering how to class the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've had another thought. This time I'm going with:

> A question!

because:

> The title is a question, the first clue is a question, the second clue is a question, and also the hint is a question.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the title.
>  This is the first clue.
>  This is the second clue.
>  This is the hint.